# Why is HttpServletResponse null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have recently updated my web page from whatever was current in 2014 to whatever is current now. I am getting an intermittent error which occurs sometimes when I got to my login page after redeploying, get this error:

```
The HttpServletRequest attribute must contain an HttpServletResponse for the attribute javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse}]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The HttpServletRequest attribute must contain an HttpServletResponse for the attribute javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository.getResponse(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.13.RELEASE.jar:5.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository.wrap(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:84) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.13.RELEASE.jar:5.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.LazyCsrfTokenRepository.generateToken(LazyCsrfTokenRepository.java:58) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.13.RELEASE.jar:5.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.victoreda.playground.controllers.BaseController.getCsrfToken(BaseController.java:317) ~[classes/:?]
    at com.victoreda.playground.controllers.SecurityController.login(SecurityController.java:69) ~[classes/:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat9-servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) [spring-webmvc-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat9-servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat9-websocket-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209) [spring-security-web-5.3.13.RELEASE.jar:5.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.13.RELEASE.jar:5.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(ExpiresFilter.java:1227) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.13.jar:5.3.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:688) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat9-catalina-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1639) [tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat9-coyote-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat9-util-9.0.31.jar:9.0.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
```

The java code that handles(?) my login page is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loginpage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error) {
    final String methodName = "login";
    Helper.logEntrance(getLogger(), methodName);

    ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView(methodName);
    if (error != null) {
        result.addObject("error", "Invalid username or password");
    }
    result.addObject("_csrf", getCsrfToken(request));
    Helper.logExit(getLogger(), methodName, result);
    return result;
}
```

And the code for `getCsrfToken` is

```
protected CsrfToken getCsrfToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // Populate CSRF token since it is not automatically populated by Spring Security
    CsrfToken token = getCsrfTokenRepository().loadToken(request);
    if (token == null) {
        token = getCsrfTokenRepository().generateToken(request);
    }
    getCsrfTokenRepository().saveToken(token, request, null);
    return token;
}
```

Looking at the Spring source code for `generateToken` I see that the error is caused here

```
private HttpServletResponse getResponse(HttpServletRequest request) {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)request.getAttribute(HTTP_RESPONSE_ATTR);
    if (response == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The HttpServletRequest attribute must contain an HttpServletResponse for the attribute " + HTTP_RESPONSE_ATTR);
    } else {
        return response;
    }
}
```

because `response` is (occasionally) `null` and, despite working on this for about 3 days, I have no idea why. My feeling is that I am missing some annotation or something (because I have upgraded the .jar files).

Comment: As I'm sure is abundantly clear, I don't really know what I am doing. More info/clarification obviously available on request.

Comment: what is your code here, and what is external library code?

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos The last block of code is Spring source code. The rest is my application. (I have edited the question to make this clear.)

Comment: spring security has built in csrf generation, so i dont really understand why you have all this custom csrf code

Comment: @Toerktumlare The first block of code responds to the /loginpage URL. The last block is Spring source code. So, I would have thought that the only bit that might be superfluous would be the middle block. I didn't write any of this code.

Comment: remove all the things that has to do with csrf `result.addObject("_csrf", getCsrfToken(request));` and the getCsrfToken function. Crsf is enabled per default when you add spring security on your classpath, or you explicitly choose to disable it. You can check the spring security documentation how to configure it. There is an entire chapter on csrf

Comment: csrf is only valid when you mutate the state of the server, simply put, when you do a POST request. Your endpoint looks like a GET, so im guessing you get a null pointer then since spring will not automatically populate the repo with the request when its a GET. But im only guessing here since this is not how you configure CSRF.

Comment: @Toerktumlare Thank you for your replies. I took out everything to do with CSRF from the Java (but not JS/JSP). And the error goes away. Which is nice. But, I can't log in anymore with a username/password (but can by clicking on the Google button). (All this code was working; it's broken since I upgraded everything to work with Ubuntu 20.04.)

Comment: @Toerktumlare Is the fact that I have "all this custom code" to do with the fact that the code was written to work with 3.2.0 and now it's 5.3.13?

Comment: I am saying that between spring security 3.2 and 5.3 a lot of new features have been added. So most likely a lot of the custom code is not needed since this functionality now exists built into spring security